# JS: Action after certain String/Text in Console

Tags: javascript, text, console

I've searched for a while, but can't find an answer.

Is it possible to execute an action in JavaScricpt after typing a specific String in the Browser Console?

Example:

```
If( console.inputText = 'Hey Guys!){
alert( 'Hey, Alex!' );
}
```

In this case, 'Hey Alex!' pops up if you type in 'Hey Guys!' in the console.

Any Ideas?

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell#readline%28%29

Answer (score 0):

The console is not designed for that. Also, each browser offers its own set of tools. So in short, **no, it's not possible**.

Another way is for your page to include a sort of console, where the user would enter text or to rely on external/special tools like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell#readline%28%29 (from @gurvinder372 comment).

By the way, here are some nice [tips and tricks for the chrome dev console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks).